# Elixir / Ecto Embedded struct - updated_at not getting updated

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have an Elixir struct with an embedded struct, following the instructions from José Valim himself:

http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2015/08/working-with-ecto-associations-and-embeds/

```
    defmodule MyApp.Post do
      use Ecto.Schema
    
      schema "posts" do
        field :title
        field :body
        embeds_many :comments, MyApp.Comment
        timestamps
      end
    end
    
    defmodule MyApp.Comment do
      use Ecto.Schema
    
      embedded_schema "comments" do
        field :body
        belongs_to :post, MyApp.Post
        timestamps
      end
    end
```

Almost everything works perfectly, with the exception of the updated_at timestamp of the embedded Comments, which seem to retain their original value after being updated.

What I mean is, if I change one of the Comments in the list and update it on the Post and save it like this:

```
my_post
|> change()
|> put_embed(:comments, comments)
|> Repo.update()
```

the update to the values works as one would expect, except the updated_at timestamp of the Comment doesn't change.

I can set it manually:

```
|> Map.put(:updated_at, DateTime.to_iso8601(DateTime.utc_now))
```

and that works, but trying to figure out why it's not being automatically set by Ecto. Using Ecto 3.5.3.  Any help would be appreciated!

Migration:

```
defmodule MyApp.Repo.Migrations.CreatePosts do
    use Ecto.Migration

    def change do
        create table(:posts) do
            add :title, :string
            add :body, :string
            add :comments, :map
            
            timestamps()
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you post the migration

Comment: Is it possible you've configured the embedded schema to not have a primary key? The lack of a primary key would prevent it from realizing the same record was being updated, and cause it to treat the record as new.

Comment: The embedded structs appear to get a cryptic looking generated key (for example 23d7409a-6028-4fe5-b97c-5c2af3706b3a), and I am able to update and delete them using that key.  The full CRUD functionality works perfectly for the embedded records, with the one exception of the updated_at timestamp not being updated.

Comment: Does the `inserted_at` value change?

Comment: Yes it has a primary key by default, that's how existing embedded records can be updated.   The inserted_at value does not change.

Answer (score 1):

[`put_embed/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#put_embed/4)'s behaviour is based on that of [`put_assoc/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#put_assoc/4), which states that:

> a map or keyword list can be given to update the associated data as long as they have matching primary keys. For example, `put_assoc(changeset, :comments, [%{id: 1, title: "changed"}])` will locate the comment with `:id` of 1 and update its title. If no comment with such id exists, one is created on the fly.

Based on the behaviour that you're commenting, I would suspect that you're not providing the `:id` field in the comments. This means that existing comments get deleted and the provided comments get inserted. To validate this hypothesis, check if the `inserted_at` or the `id` field changes with each execution.

Comment: I am providing the ID.  It is updating the fields in the correct comment(s) as one would expect, the only thing it's not doing is updating the updated_at.

Comment: @Seaweedsalad Hm... at this stage then I'd suggest you provide a reproducible snippet, otherwise it's a guessing game.